# Pipe sql query to find command

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, sqlite

OS: RockyLinux 8.5

This command works wonderfully:

```
sqlite3 files.db "select file from A;" | rsync -R -av --files-from=/dev/stdin /SOURCE /DESTINATION/Out
```

result without pipe:

```
sqlite3 files.db "select file from A;"

file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

I'm trying to use the same method but pipe to a find command.

```
sqlite3 files.db "select file from A;" | find -type f -name /dev/sdin
```

It does not return any values.

Comment: What's the output if you don't pipe it into find?

Comment: 1) `-name` never matches because names never contain `/` (GNU find warns about this); 2) `find` doesn't read its stdin

Comment: are you trying to discover which files from the sql listing actually exist? for that you could do something like: `sqlite3 files.db "select file from A;" | xargs ls 2>/dev/null`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us i) your operating system so we know what `find` implementation you have; ii) an example of the output your SQL command gives. Remember, we don't have access to your DB we have no idea what to expect. iii) what `find` command you want to run. Are these file names without paths and you want to find files with that name on your system? Are they with paths? What directory should `find` search through?

Comment: the output is a list of files.

Answer (score 1):

Your `find` command looks in the current directory and downwards through any other subdirectories for a file (`-type f`) named `/dev/stdin`:

> ```
> find -type f -name /dev/stdin
> ```

It doesn't read or use *stdin* at all. It will also fail to match anything because `/dev/stdin` is an impossible name for a file (file *names* cannot contain `/`). GNU `find` (at least) returns this warning:

> find: warning: ‘-name’ matches against basenames only, but the given pattern contains a directory separator (‘/’), thus the expression will evaluate to false all the time.  Did you mean ‘-wholename’?

If you want to use `find` to determine pathnames for the set of names returned by your SQL query you will have to iterate across the set, and hope that none of the file names contain a newline character. Here's one way of achieving this:

```
sqlite3 files.db "select file from A;" |
    while IFS= read -r file
    do
        find -type f -name "$file"
    done
```

---

Example scenario. Assumes the presence of at least one of the three named sample files `p.c`, `sc`, `args` somewhere in or under the current directory:

```
sqlite3 files.db <<'EOF'
create table A ( file char(255) not null );
insert into A values ('p.c');
insert into A values ('sc');
insert into A values ('args');
EOF

sqlite3 files.db "select file from A;" |
    while IFS= read -r file; do find -type f -name "$file"; done

./p.c
./sc
./bin/sc
./chroot/bin/args
./bin/args
```

Comment: I appreciate it.  It does not find files in sub-folders.

Comment: Then I suspect the output you have provided doesn't match your reality, or your subdirectories are elsewhere in the filesystem and referenced by symbolic links. (I tested it here before posting - I've added my scenario to the question, @GarySchermer)

Comment: This is a reasonable solution for finding 3 files. If the O.P. needs to search for many files, then creating a list for `find` to use, like `\( -name 'file1.txt' -o -name 'file2.txt' -o -name 'file3.txt' -o ..... \)` would be much faster to run. But constructing such a command would be a medium-sized headache AND would have to not exceed the MAX_CMD_LINE_SIZE (there is an  official name for this), which would complicate things further. I won't have time to figure that out (-;! Cheers.

Comment: @shellter you could build the comnmand line segment fairly easily using something like `bash`'s arrays. There's a fixed maximum defined by `getconf ARG_MAX`, which on my Pi is around 2,000,000 characters (bytes)

Comment: No criticism intended. Sorry if it came across that way. I probably should have posted that to the original question as my "advice" was intended for them. Some shells have a MAX_WORDS value too, but it is hard to find it documented except in  Sun Unix documentation (that is where I used to see it).

Comment: @shellter no worries. I've removed my first reply as it was a little harsh, sorry.